# What are the pros and cons of template and polymorphism based approaches in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism

I wrote a program where the type of a variable is not known at compile time. It is asked to the user at run time. In the first program version, a part of the code was repeated. The modifications concerned the type of variable used. In second and third program versions, a template-based approach and a polymorphism-based approach (with abstract class and virtual function) were used.

All programs run fine. But I wonder what are the pros and cons of this two approaches, when one is most appropriate than the other and if another approaches exist ?

To clarify my question, this an example below :

**First version (with code repetition)**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
    public : float lgth;
    public : void getLgth() { cin >> lgth;}
};

class Square : public Shape {
    public : float calcArea() { return lgth * lgth; }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    public : float calcArea() { return 3.14 * lgth * lgth; }
};

int main() {
    char shape_type;

    cout <<"Shape Type (c/s) ? ";
    cin >> shape_type;
    if (shape_type == 'c') {
      Circle my_shape;
      cout << "Shape Length ? ";
      my_shape.getLgth();
      cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape.calcArea() << endl;
    }
    else if (shape_type == 's') {
      Square my_shape;
      // --- Code repetition ---
      cout << "Shape Length ? ";
      my_shape.getLgth();
      cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape.calcArea() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Template based approach**

A template is added

```
template <typename TShape>
// requires(std::derived_from<TShape, Shape>) // C++20 constraint
void do_job()
{
    TShape my_shape;
    std::cout << "Shape Length ?";
    my_shape.getLgth();
    std::cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape.calcArea() << std::endl;
}
```

And the main is modified as follow

```
if (shape_type == 'c') {
    do_job<Circle>();
} else if (shape_type == 's') {
    do_job<Square>();
}
```

**polymorphism-based approach**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// abstract class : Shape
// virtual function : calcArea
class Shape {
    public :
        float lgth;
        virtual ~Shape() = default;
        void getLgth() { cin >> lgth; }
        virtual float calcArea() = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape {
    public :
        float calcArea() override { return lgth * lgth; }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    public :
        float calcArea() override { return 3.14 * lgth * lgth; }
};

int main() {
    char shape_type;
    Shape* my_shape;

    cout << "Shape Type (c/s) ? ";
    cin >> shape_type;

    if (shape_type == 'c') {
        my_shape = new Circle;
    }
    else if (shape_type == 's') {
        my_shape = new Square;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unknown type!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Shape Length ? ";
    my_shape->getLgth();
    cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape->calcArea() << endl;

    delete my_shape;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's comparing apples to oranges, they are doing different kind of polymorphism, templates are doing compile-time polymorphism, and virtual functions are doing runtime polymorphism, you can use runtime polymorphism in place of compile time polymorphism at a performance cost, but you cannot use compile-time polymorphism to replace runtime polymorphism, you should first decide whether you want compile-time polymorphism or runtime polymorphism before picking the right tool for the job.

Comment: To answer to people that vote to close this question. It is not an opinion based question. I do not want an answer _this one is better than this one_. I thought I was clear in my question. Suggestion to improve it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ahmed AEK. Thanks a lot for your answer. It is the kind of answer I am expecting : compile-time vs run-time polymorphism and the impact on the execution time. In a previous comment, you mentioned std::variant with dynamic dispatch and type-erasure. Do you have some links to suggest with these approaches or examples ?

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn6OqefuH08) by klaus is a good source to learn type-erasure, there's also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=wU8hQvU8aKM) of rust's polymorphism using type-erasure, the concept in c++ is explained in klaus's video too, variants with dynamic dispatch or double dispatch are somewhat a mix between the visitor design pattern and type-erasure, its a mix between runtime and compile-time polymorphism that has a few benefits and downsides over both.

Comment: @Stef1611 - If the question is not opinion based, it is instead to broad. Like "What are the pros and cons of a Porsche vs a Pickup truck?". Perhaps different use cases?

Comment: it's basically about what do you know at compile-time vs what you know at run-time, do you know the type or the operation or both ? maybe you know the type at compile-time but you don't know the operation so you can use variants, maybe you know the operations but you don't know the type so you can use type-erasure, maybe you don't know both so you use a visitor with double dispatch, maybe you know both so you can use your template solution,  etc ...

Comment: @ahmed. Thanks a lot. I will try

Comment: you will not be able to understand the pros and cons by means of some made up `Shapes` and `Square` and `Circle` example. Such toy examples are good to see how each approach is implemented, but they have limits. Pros and cons you will only see when you have real requirements that need to be fulfilled, then you pick the tool that fits. As others mentioned "whats the pro and cons or a screwdriver and a hammer?" is too broad. Because a hammer and a screwdriver have very different areas of usage, an answer would have to explain all uses of a hammer and all uses of a screwdriver to be complete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any pros and cons. Templates and inheritance are distinct mechanisms solving different problems. You can sometimes force one to be used when the other is more appropriate, especially in very simple examples where you ultimately just do one thing with the object, but in general, it's best to use templates where templates are the appropriate solution, and inheritance where inheritance is the appropriate solution.

From a more or less theoretical point of view: templates provide a common implementation for different interfaces, and inheritance provides different implementations for a common interface. For example, in the standard, `std::vector` is a template: `std::vector<double>` provides a function `push_back( double )`, for example, where as `std::vector<int>` provides `push_back( int )`. But both functions have the same implementation. On the other hand, the interface to `std::ostream` is exactly the same, although what happens to the characters being output (the implementation) is completely different for `std::ofstream` and `std::ostringstream`.

Another important difference is that templates are resolved at compile time, but virtual functions at run-time. This means that calling a function template (or a member function of a class template) will typically be faster (but this may be offset by the need of extra code to select which function to call explicitly), and there may be more possibilities for the compiler to analyze what is going on, for better error checking or optimization. On the other hand, it means that any call site can only call one specific instance of the function; if you have multiple call sites and want to call different functions at each, templates require that you determine the type explicitly at each call site, with separate function calls for each different function.

Answer (score 0):

**Function Templates:**

**Pros:**

*Generic:* Function templates let us write generic code that works with different types.

*Code Reusability:* Template lets us reuse the same template can be used for different data types.

**Cons:**

*Memory and compilation:* Using templates for different data types leads to the compiler generating copies of code for each different data type which takes up more memory and results in slower compilation because the lines of code to execute increase.

*Complexity:* Debugging templated code can be challenging when multiple parameters.

```
template <typename T>
T multiply(T a, T b) 
{
return a * b;
}
```

**Inheritance:**

**Pros:**

*Code Reusability:* Inheritance allows us to reuse part of the code of another class by creating a base class and derived classes.

*Protection:* Inheritance by making the relation between base and derived class either protected or private lets us limit the privacy and data visibility of our code for end-users.

**Cons:**

*High Dependence* [Tight Coupling]: In inheritance base and derived classes are highly dependent any changes in the base class may require modifications in the derived class. This makes the code less flexible and harder to maintain.

*Multiple Inheritance Ambiguity [Diamond Problem]*: Multiple inheritance can result in the diamond problem, where ambiguity arises when a class inherits from two classes that have a common base class.
Look at the following code to understand the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A 
{
public:
void display() 
{
    cout << "A" << endl;
}
};
class B : public A 
{
public:
void display() 
{
   cout << "B" << endl;
}
};
class C : public A
{
public:
void show() 
{
    cout << "C" << endl;
}
};
class D : public B, public C
{
};
int main() 
{
D myD;
myD.show();  // Which show method should be called?
return 0;
}
```

**Polymorphism:**

**Pros:**

*Dynamic:* Polymorphism allows dynamic binding, enabling the selection of the appropriate function at runtime using virtual functions.

*Static*: Using function and operator overloading for compile-time execution.

**Cons:**

*Performance:* Dynamic polymorphism involves the use of virtual functions, which can introduce a slower performance because dynamic allocation at run time is more time-consuming compared to static binding at compile time.

*Complexity:* Polymorphic code can be more complex, and understanding the flow of execution may be challenging for large codebases.

**How to Decide:**

**Function Templates:**
Use function templates when we need generic code that can work with different types without sacrificing performance.

**Inheritance:**
Use inheritance when we have a clear "is-a" relationship between classes and want to leverage code reuse.

**Polymorphism:**
Use polymorphism when we need dynamic decision-making to call function.